# OpenSSL Signature different each time

Tags: openssl

I have a file that I am generating a signature for using OpenSSL, and each time I generate the signature, it is different to the last time.

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign update_key.pem TERM010134.bin > Update.sig
```

Anyone able to tell me why that might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what algorithm (determined by key type) and padding you use.

If the key is a DSA key, or an ECC key used for ECDSA, those algorithms normally use randomized signatures to remain secure, and OpenSSL does so. (There is a variant scheme that makes k unique and unpredictable without making it truly random, but it is not widely used and not implemented in OpenSSL.)

If the key is an RSA key, OpenSSL supports 3 RSA paddings other than `none`: `pkcs1` (more exactly the type-1 scheme of PKCS#1 through v1.5, now retronymed RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5), `pss`, and `x931`. `dgst -sign` for RSA defaults to `pkcs`, which is deterministic and should not produce varying results; if it does please edit your question with details (preferably using a test key). Only if you specify `-sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss` should you get a randomized result.

Note RSA *encryption* is different, and OpenSSL supports two paddings other than `none`: `pkcs1` (this time meaning RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5) and `oaep`, both of which are randomized; the newer OAEP is randomized in a way that is *provably* secure which the older v1_5 scheme does not.

Answer (score 0):

In cryptography some random token are used as input in signature and encryption algorithms to avoid traffic analysis or dictionary attacks. You get a new different signature each time you run the command because a new, fresh random token is generated and used into the algorithm.